# Is it good practice to lock a thread in order to make things transactional in winforms?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, multithreading

This is a old school winforms application that I am working with, and they design pattern that was used is as follows:

Whenever you need to make things transactional, a operation is performed on its own thread, and the thread is locked (a specific lock object is used for each operation), and then a call is made to the wcf service, some local objects are updated, then the lock is released.

Is this good practise?

Comment: As long as you don't create a deadlock or turn the code into spagetti, of course you can do it.

Comment: If only the "local" objects are updated as you say then why are you locking at all? I think we're going to need some more information. Code is always helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but be careful of multithreading and have a good read on it as too many locks might create a deadlock situation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite know what you mean, "lock a thread." Is it something like this?

```
static object ThreadLock = new object();

void ThreadProc(object state)
{
    lock (ThreadLock)
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

If so, there's nothing really wrong with that design. Your UI thread spawns a thread that's supposed to execute that code, and the lock prevents multiple threads from executing concurrently. It's a little bit wasteful in that you could potentially have many threads queued up behind the lock, but in practice you probably don't have more than one or two threads waiting. There are more efficient ways to do it (implement a task queue of some sort), but what you have is simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are not waiting on multiple lock objects, this should be fine.  Deadlock occurs when you have a situation like this:

Thread A:

```
lock (lockObject1)
{
    // Do some stuff

    lock (lockObject2)
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

Thread B:

```
lock (lockObject2)
{
    // Do some stuff

    lock (lockObject1)
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

If you happen to lock lockObject1 in thread A, and thread B locks lockObject2 before thread A locks it, then both threads will be waiting for an object that is locked in another thread, and neither will unlock because each is waiting while having an object locked.  This is an oversimplified example -- there are many ways one can end up in this situation.

To avoid deadlock, do not wait on a second object while you have a first object locked.  If you lock one object at a time like this, you can't get deadlocked because eventually, the locking thread will release the object a waiting thread needs.  So for example, the above should be unrolled:

Thread A:

```
lock (lockObject1)
{
        // Do some stuff
}

lock (lockObject2)
{
        // Do some stuff
}
```

Thread B:

```
lock (lockObject2)
{
        // Do some stuff
}

lock (lockObject1)
{
        // Do some stuff
}
```

In this case, each lock operation will complete without trying to acquire another resources, and so deadlock is avoided.

Answer (score 0):

This is not making the action transactional.  I would take that to mean that either the entire operation succeeds or it has no effect -- if I update two local object inside your synchronization block, an error with the second does not rollback changes to the first.

Also, there is nothing stopping the main thread from using the two objects while they are being updated -- it needs to cooperate by also locking.

Locking in the background thread is only meaningful if you also lock when you use those objects in the main thread.